# go map search using values in a map

Tags: go, maps

I have a map structured like map[string][]string. Now I have to find all keys which have the required values in the value slice. I can do something like this:

```
// allsvc is map[string][]string
var newsl []string


    for k, v :=  range  allsvc {
        for _, val := range v {
            if v == "type1" || v == "type2" {
                newsl.append(k)
            }
        }

    }
```

The map allsvc has atleast a half million entries at any given time, and the lookup is quite frequent. I get the allsvc map as an ouput of a 3rd party library and then I have to search in it using values in my api and provide a response. Given the high frequency of lookup not using keys but with values, the way i have done it makes my api response time to be in the seconds. Is there a way to better performance (speed of lookup)?

Comment: How often is the map updated? Do you get the map once and then have to query multiple times? If that's the case, it might be worth re-arranging the map when you get it to then make the queries faster.

Comment: I doubt your values unique? if it is by chance then create `map[string]bool` using values (may be you can have one map per party). BTW `val` from second `for` is not used in your snippet.

Comment: @eugenioy can you please give insight about `re-arranging the map`?

Comment: @eugenioy :  the map is obtained every time an api call is made ... flow is : consumer calls myapi , myapi goes and gets the latest info and populates map, does a lookup and returns value to consumer .... i initially thought about re-arranging the map, but on every call, it gives a performance hit...

Comment: @mg03: when you "get the latest info and populate map", can't you populate it with a different structure like the one I suggested in my answer? If not, I don't see many options... Another alternative would be for you to avoid getting the latest information on each call (having a cached version of the map), but that of course would only work if your consumer can tolerate not getting 100% fresh information.

Answer (score 2):

If you will query that map multiple times, it might be worth spending some time re-arranging it when you get it so that you can then query it faster.

It seems you need to invert the relationships, making the values in `allsvc` the keys in the new map, and having the keys as values so that you can then just make lookups in the new map.

This can be a way to re-arrange the map:

```
func arrangeMap(oldMap map[string][]string) map[string][]string {
    newMap := make(map[string][]string)
    for k, v :=  range  oldMap {
        for _, val := range v {
            newMap[val] = append(newMap[val], k)
        }
    }
    return newMap
}
```

See here a playground showing the idea:

https://play.golang.org/p/0ThZlX9xUn

Comment: Thanks for giving an example.